# clickhouse sum arrays at same index

Tags: clickhouse

Having the table A below:

```
    units
   [1,1,1]
   [2,5,2]
   [3,2,6]
```

I would like to query something like:
select id, sum(units) from A group by id
And get the following result:

```
 [6,8,9]
```

Comment: sumForEach(units) https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-foreach

Comment: + see examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190835/303298, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62814485/303298